# c# datatable add where condition on array of string

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, datatable

This is my code:

```
DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
            var result = (from row in InBoundtable.AsEnumerable()
                         group row by row.Field <string> ("Date") into grp
                         select new {
                             AbandonCalls = grp.Sum((r) => Double.Parse(r["AvgAbandonedCalls"].ToString())),
                             Date = ((DateTime.Parse(grp.Key)) - epoch).TotalMilliseconds
                         }).ToList();
```

where `InBoundtable` is a datatable.

now I have a string array `campains`

my question is there a way so in the select statement above I can make where the `campain` field, which is a string field, is either one of the values in the `campains` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Contains("campain value")`:

```
var query =  from row in InBoundtable.AsEnumerable()
             where campains.Contains(row.Field<string>("Campain"))
             group row by row.Field <string> ("Date") into grp
             select new {
                 AbandonCalls = grp.Sum(r => Double.Parse(r["AvgAbandonedCalls"].ToString())),
                 Date = ((DateTime.Parse(grp.Key)) - epoch).TotalMilliseconds
             };
var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: note that i've edited the answer since you should exclude rows before the `group by`.

Comment: that is what I was going to ask you about. I am trying it

Comment: if the array of string is empty, will that code throw exception? or just empty result?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: it won't throw an exception if it's empty, only if it's null. Read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.100).ASPX